# Django URL start with special character "?"

Tags: django

I'm trying to acceed to this url: https://www.topmoonitor.com/?a=details&lid=19

The problem is django don't care of the "?" before a=details&lid=19 and redirect me to the home page on this URL:

```
 path('', views.index, name='index'),
```

If i remove the "?" it's work properly.

My current code :

```
path('?a=details&lid=<slug:lid>/', views.button_img, name="button_img"),
```

I tried this but still not working :/

```
re_path(r'?a=details&lid=(?P<lid>\d+)', views.button_img, name="button_img"),
```

Do you have some idea please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you should access your `kwargs` in the `views`:

**urls.py**

```
path('', views.myview)
```

**views.py**

```
def myview(request):
    print(request.GET)  # or any other method you are using...
```

So if you have `https://www.topmoonitor.com/?a=details&lid=19` you will get:

```
<QueryDict: {'a': ['details'], 'lid': ['19']}>
```